# how to add prefix to UUID generated by hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, uuid

i generate UUID like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="id", unique = true, length=36)
private String id;
```

but i still haven't found a way to add prefix to generated UUID (or to generate UUID with added prefix).

if i use getter method to add a prefix, actual UUID is still UUID without prefix.
appreciate the help.

Comment: Why do you actually need to add a prefix to the UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found an answer. maybe not straight-forward, but you can implement hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator and create your own custom id generator class.